# golang: mimetype error for http.FileServer(....)

Tags: angular, go

I am using Angular for frontend and go for the backend. When I try to load my application (browser=firefox) I see the following error in the console.

```
GEThttp://localhost:3000/polyfills.d103671dae517af0.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]

Loading failed for the module with source “http://localhost:3000/runtime.7cfe7dd4f95969d6.js”. ng:12:1
Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/polyfills.d103671dae517af0.js” was
 blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/plain”).
```

I checked online and there is a year old bug open for a similar issue on windows https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32350 for which the solution is Windows Specific.

I am using Linux(  Linux Mint 20.2)

My code is:

```
package main 
import( 
        "net/http" 
        "fmt" 
        "log" 
) 
func main(){ 
        port:="3000" 
        fixer := http.NewServeMux() 
        fixer.Handle("/ng/",http.StripPrefix("/ng/",http.FileServer(http.Dir("./ng")))) 
        server := &http.Server{ 
                Addr:    fmt.Sprintf(":"+port), 
                //Handler: handlers.New(), 
                Handler: fixer, 
        }   
        if err := server.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed { 
                log.Printf("%v", err) 
        } else { 
                log.Println("Server closed!") 
        } 
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The title is about a MIME type error, while the question is talking about a 404 ("not found") error. They do contradict themselves. Please work on improving your question.

Comment: The last line of the error message says
`....js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/plain”).`

 the expected type is text/javascript while the one sent by Go server is text/plain

Hence the title say's that there is a mime type error.

Comment: The content-type is text/plain because it's a 404 response. It's a 404 response because you registered the FileServer under the `/ng/` path prefix, but that prefix isn't present in `/polyfills.d103671dae517af0.js`.

Comment: Which frontend component performs the loading? It clearly has a bug as it checks the mime type of the response ignoring its non-2xx status code.

Comment: @Peter, your comment helped me to fix this. If you convert it to an answer I will accept it.